# Serializing Int values to char* buffer in ANSI C

Tags: c, pointers, serialization, segmentation-fault, memcpy

I tried to serialize a structure field (int) to a char* buffer but I think I am doing things wrong.

This is what I am using to copy this field.

`memcpy(payload + offset, &packet->payload.offset, sizeof(long int));`

packet->payload.offset is a long int and contains the value '5' (hardcoded), note that:

If I print: `printf("offset: %ld \n", packet->payload.offset);`  I get: `offset: 5`

But if I print: `printf("offset: %ld \n",&packet->payload.offset)`, I get: `offset: 167120959`

If in memcopy I remove the '&'  to the second argument to write '5' to the buffer it causes Segmentation Fault, but if I don't, it copies 167120959 (which I supose it is it's address) to the buffer instead of the actual value.

Thank you very much for your help! I tried to be as descriptive as possible, hope you can help me out.

Answer (score 2):

> But if I print: `printf("offset: %ld \n",&packet->payload.offset)`, I
>   get: `offset: 167120959`

That's because you're printing an address, not a value. Your "serialization" method is OK (endianness aside) because `memcpy` expects addresses.

> I remove the '&' to the second argument to write '5' to the buffer
>   [...] but if I don't, it copies 167120959 (which I supose it is it's
>   address) to the buffer instead of the actual value.

Wrong. It copies `sizeof(long int)` bytes **from that address**.

Comment: That's what I expected, but when I de-serialize the stream, and print packet->payload.offset I get 167120959 when I was suposed to get "5"

Answer (score 0):

```
But if I print: printf("offset: %ld \n",&packet->payload.offset), I get: offset: 167120959
```

That's wrong, it prints the address of `packet->payload.offset` instead of `packet->payload.offset` itself.

Memcpy has to be supplied with the address of the variable, else it can't modify it (there's no byref parameter passing in C). So you pass `memcpy()` the address of the variale, but `printf()` only needs to read it, so you can (and should) pass the variable directly.

Comment: got your point, but how am I suposed to do to write the variable content to the char* ?

Comment: char *buf = (wherever it points to); *(int *)buf = packet->payload.offset;

Comment: Cant I use memcpy() to do so ?

Comment: you can, but then that's the same (good) method that you used-- then why are you asking?

Comment: thanks for answering :)  Because when I use memcopy as detailed in my question, memcopy writes the address into the char* instead of the variable content.